# Android - Button OnTouch event change focus of Button

Tags: android

I have an App with 10 Buttons. Everytime the User presses on one Button A TextView should change. And if the User changes the focus and ,oves its finger to right, to the next button(without taking the finger off the screen) the seond button should be focused.

I tried it with setting an OnTouchListner to all buttons, but once the finger is moved the focus still stays on the first button:

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                txt1.settext("1");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I hope you understood what I mean and can help me with this.

Thanks

Edit:

I found an Application which does that, here is a Video, so you can visualise what I mean.
Notice how I move the mouse(the finger in this case) and the Boxes change its focus:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRVFpNrBmsA&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start in your onTouch() you should handle the events...

Something like

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) {
               txt1.settext("1");
            } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT){
               txt1.settext("0");
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Not sure if those are the proper actions to check against but it is just to give the idea.

Also I believe you should return true otherwise it means that the event wasn't processed and it gets stuck.

Comment: The above code won't compile. It should be event.getAction() not just event